# Use spinbox values as textvariable for another spinbox (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want to create two spinboxes: the first one with *int* from 1 to 20 and the second one with *int* from 1 to the number in the first spinbox.

This is what I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

mainWin = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.IntVar()
sp1 = tk.Spinbox(mainWin, from_=1, to=20, textvariable=var1, state="readonly")
sp1.grid()

var2 = tk.IntVar()
sp2= tk.Spinbox(mainWin, from_=1, to=var1.get(), textvariable=var2, state="readonly")
#sp2= tk.Spinbox(mainWin, from_=1, to=int(var1.get()), textvariable=var2, state="readonly") -> Also doesn't work
sp2.grid()

mainWin.mainloop()
```

The second spinbox doesn't have any value.
I have tried different ways and I can't find any that works.

Comment: A Combobox that has values from 1 to var1 is another possible implementation. I tried it but wasn't able to make it work. It remained empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `sp2` you set the value to `var1.get()`, but to have it change with `var1` you will have to give it a function which reacts to changes in `sp1`. As with buttons you can specify a callback function:

```
sp1 = tk.Spinbox( ... , command=callback_function)
```

Also, the spinbox does not seem to get it if I set both `from_` and `to` to the same value, so I set it explicitly whenever `var1.get()` returns 1.

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

mainWin = tk.Tk()

def update_sp2(event=None):
    sp2.config(to=var1.get())
    if var1.get() == 1: var2.set(1) # Needed to set spinbox value = 1

var1 = tk.IntVar()
sp1 = tk.Spinbox(mainWin, from_=1, to=20, textvariable=var1, command=update_sp2)
sp1.grid()

var2 = tk.IntVar()
sp2 = tk.Spinbox(mainWin, from_=1, to=1, textvariable=var2)
sp2.grid()
var2.set(1)     # Needed to set spinbox value = 1

mainWin.mainloop()
```